# Solving $\sqrt{x^2-5} = x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't now how to solve this equation, and how to get rid of $\sqrt{x^2-5}$

$\sqrt{x^2-5} = x-1$

Comment: what is ride? What is the question?

Comment: Did you at least try to square both sides?

Comment: yes, i know now solution but why can we square each number separately?

Comment: The answer you accepted was INCORRECT, by the way

Comment: yes i see that, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

squaring $\sqrt{x^2 - 5} = (x-1)$ gives you $x^2 - 5 = x^2 - 2x + 1$ cancel $x^2$ you get $2x = 6$ and $x = 3$.

Comment: Thx. Why can we square each number separately? Because x-1 it was written without parentheses.

Comment: Whatever you do to one side, you must do to the other.

Comment: @KristinaVidaković, the right hand side is $x -1$ with or without a parenthesis. for example if you substitute $x = 4$ left hand side evaluates to $\sqrt {11}$ and the right hand side to $1.$ and you can see that they are not equal so we say that $x = 4$ is not a solution. but when you subs $x = 3,$ you see that both side is $2$ so we say that $x=3$ is a solution. usually when you are squaring, this may introduce additional solutions, so you have to check each of the supposed solution to make sure it is.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You should first determine the domain of validity of the equation (when each component of the equation is defined). When $x$ belongs to this domain, note that the square root is $\ge 0$, so that if $x\le 1$, the inequality is automatically satisfied. If $x\ge 1$, both terms are $\ge 0$, so that you can compare them by comparing their squares.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ (\sqrt x)^2 = x.$$

You should be able to take it from here ... all that's left to do is expansion, and grouping.

Comment: Your hint is slightly misleading (it does not matter here, but could be good for catching extraneous solutions). It should be $(\sqrt{x})^2 , x \geq 0$.

Comment: $x > 0$ is implied by the $\sqrt \cdot$ in the equation ... the question is tagged (algebra-precalculus). I doubt it is complex.

Comment: It is implied in the LHS, not the RHS. On the other hand one could choose to make convection that when roots are involved in an equation (or string of equations) then the implication is propagated to the entire string. This is why I said misleading and not incorrect. When people know what they are doing, this is safe. On the other hand when people are learning, it is best to carry orotund the extra data about domains, as it will allow for quick checking of extraneous solutions. A real pedant(which I am not), however would say that $x$ is a different animal than $x,x\geq 0$.

Comment: Same variable on both sides. I won't argue about this. But, when I was learning algebra and pre-calculus in high school, we never bothered to learn complex numbers or consider negative roots. Perhaps your education was different.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{x^2-5} = x-1$$

$$x^2 - 5 = ({x-1})^2$$

$$x^2 = x^2 -2x +1 + 5$$

$$x^2 -x^2 = -2x + 6$$

$$2x = 6$$

$$x = 3$$

Sorry I kind of had a brain fart today.

Comment: This is false. $(a+b)^2\ne a^2+b^2$